# Cassandra CPP Driver

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cassandra, installation

Really basic issue. I'm trying to install the Datastax Cassandra C++ driver on my Ubuntu 16.0.4 machine. It really shouldn't be that difficult. I've installed all dependencies using dpkg and installed the cassandra driver deb file. But I can't find (or #include) the cassandra.h file.
Running

```
$ locate cassandra.h
```

returns nothing and running

```
$ locate cassandra*
```

returns a whole mess of files from cqlsh, the casssandra config files, etc, but no header files for the cpp driver. 
Additionally, cassandra-cpp-driver doesn't show up in dpkg -l (though apt-get and dpkg -i say it's already installed).

Any help getting this installed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DataStax C/C++ Driver for Apache Cassandra is currently not available from the Ubuntu official repository.

There are `.deb` packages for Ubuntu which are available as mentioned in the DataStax project documentation on github `datastax/cpp-driver` repository from this location:

http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/

If you are using Ubuntu 16.04, the last `.deb` available are under `ubuntu/16.04/cassandra/v2.7.0/`.

You will find the `cassandra.h` file in `cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.7.0-1_amd64.deb`, which you need to download and install with `dpkg`.

**The suffix `dev` in a Debian or Ubuntu package denotes a package meant for developing programs, containing, in particular, header files**.

```
dpkg -i cassandra-cpp-driver-dev_2.7.0-1_amd64.deb
```

The header will get installed in the usual location under Linux for header files that your compiler should find without a problem: `/usr/include/cassandra.h`.

it will also install:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcassandra_static.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/cassandra.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/cassandra_static.pc
/usr/share/doc/cassandra-cpp-driver-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/cassandra-cpp-driver-dev/copyright
```

which you will need for static linking and for pkgconfig to work properly.

What you may have installed is `cassandra-cpp-driver_2.7.0-1_amd64.deb` which contains the `libcassandra.so.2.7.0` that is the shared object (dynamic) library binary file,.. although whatever you installed should indeed come in the result of a `dkpg -l` query such as:

```
dpkg -l | grep cassandra
```

If you installed anything from an unofficial source, I would suggest you uninstall these first, and install the provided `.deb` for your plaform from the official source.

Follow the documentation's instructions for making your first program with this library.